# Create endpoint url for boto3 using API Gateway

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, boto3

At the moment my application uses boto3 to access AWS resources. However I'd like to instead use the API Gateway to front the AWS Services used so that everything is funnelled through the API Gateway instead of directly to the services.

I have the API Gateway working, but how can I tell boto3 to use this new endpoint because the API Gateway endpoints are setup on a per action basis. i.e., there's one for ListQueues and another for CreateQueue.

Using boto3 with the endpoint-url parameter gives me this error:

> botocore.parsers.ResponseParserError: Unable to parse response (not well-formed (invalid token): line 1, column 0), invalid XML received:
>   {"message":"Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'execute-api'. "}

Comment: if you are using boto3, what is the reason you would want to use an API Gateway endpoint?  What advantage does this provide? That seems like... calling your mother and asking her to hand her phone to your brother, instead of just calling your brother on his own phone.  Can you help us understand what problem you are trying to solve by funneling things through API Gateway?  I'm not saying there is no valid use case... but I don't see it yet.

Comment: This is so that we can keep our firewall rules simple by only allowing API Gateway traffic.

Comment: I think you'll find that to be an exercise in futility. Your endpoint does not have a fixed address.

Comment: on API gateway as a single point of entry for AWS services - i kinda think @vonec's thoughts are reasonable - API Gwy will allow to unify / apply your well defined security filters to  access AWS resources and services. less things to manage, no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research, the real answer is this is actually not possible because boto3 library does not support API Gateway as one of the services it makes available.

See here:
https://github.com/boto/botocore/issues/1140

There is currently an open feature request to allow boto3 to make calls to an API Gateway resource:
https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/1246

If anyone knows something I don't know please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

When creating your client, you can pass the keyword parameter `endpoint_url` which lets you override the default URL `botocore` would construct for the target service otherwise.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sqs', endpoint_url="https://your.api.gateway.url.here")
```

You will need some management here since it sounds like you have read-only API Gateway endpoints, and then some that have write capabilities.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that, but it looks like I need some help with how the API Gateway endpoint should be setup. Could you point me to some info on how the API Gateway should be setup?

Comment: What part is giving you issues? The actual API Gateway URL? Or is the client responding with errors?

Comment: The API Gateway seems to be fine if I access directly from a REST client, it's just when I use it as an endpoint-url I get an error (which I've added to the OP)

Comment: @vonec Looks like boto can't authenticate properly. Are you proxying all the authentication as well, or do you need to skip credentials entirely?

Comment: I'm using the AWS_IAM authentication with API Gateway. Should I be using a different setting? because I don't see any options to proxy the authentication.